# Why does a call to a mocked object from within a generator fail to test correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, generator, python-unittest

In the following code under test the Generator class contains two methods each of which calls the `next_count` method of the Counter class.

These two calls to `next_count` are tested with two almost identical tests using `assert_called_with`. The test of the generator method fails. Why? How can this call be tested?

**Code Under Test**

generator.py

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1

    def next_count(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count


class Generator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = Counter()

    def direct_call(self):
        self.counter.next_count()

    def iter_event(self):
        while True:
            yield self.counter.count
            self.counter.next_count()
```

**Test Module**

test_generator.py

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock

import generator


class Generator(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        p = unittest.mock.patch('generator.Counter')
        self.addCleanup(p.stop)
        self.mock_counter = p.start()

    def test_next_count_called_in_direct_call(self):  # Passes
        g = generator.Generator()
        g.direct_call()
        self.mock_counter.assert_called_with()

    def test_next_count_called_in_iter_event(self):  # Fails
        g = generator.Generator()
        count_gen = g.iter_event()
        next(count_gen)
        next(count_gen)
        self.mock_counter.next_count.assert_called_with()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with generators. You test 2 different things, and tested the wrong thing in both tests.

Your two tests test something different:

```
def test_next_count_called_in_direct_call(self):  # Passes
    # ...
    self.mock_counter.assert_called_with()
```

This tests if the *class* was called. It is indeed called, as `Counter()`. Remember that `mock_counter` mocked the *class*, not an instance.

```
def test_next_count_called_in_iter_event(self):  # Fails
    # ...
    self.mock_counter.next_count.assert_called_with()
```

This tests if an attribute `Counter.next_count` was called. This was never called, because it is instead called on the instance.

The correct test is to see if that attribute *on an instance* is called:

```
self.mock_counter.return_value.next_count.assert_called_with()
```

or

```
self.mock_counter().next_count.assert_called_with()
```

Use this is *both tests*.

Because `mock_counter` is the class, it could perhaps be better named `MockCounter`.

In future, print out the [`mock_calls` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#Mock.mock_calls) of your mock; it'll show what *was* called instead. For both tests this prints:

```
[call(), call().next_count()]
```